# How to setup a local proxy that saves all traffic?

Tags: video, proxy

I'm looking for a solution that looks like the network tab of developer tools in browsers where I can see all resources, but in a way that everything is saved to the disk on the fly. I saw something like this in some proxies like Burp Suite. The point of all this would be to download videos or streams that not even youtube-dl can handle. There are some rare video hosts or even a private Vimeo video type that I think cannot be saved without this. If the proxy would save all video segments or just all data per individual request, I could make use of that.